# Third order non linear ODE - can anyone help me spot my error?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ode:

$$y'''(1+y'^2) - 2y'y''^2 = 0 $$

I used the substitution: $y'=v,$ where $y'' = v'v$, and $y''' = v(v''v+v'^2)$, since $v=v(y)$

After plugging that in, I get the following equation:

$$v(v''v+v'^2)(1+v^2)-2v^3v'^2$$

I used order reduction one more time:

$v'=u, v''-u'u$, since $u=u(y)$

The equation transforms to:

$$u'uv^2(v^2+1) - vu^2(v^2-1)$$

The solution of this ODE is $u = \frac{c_1(v^2+1)}{v}$

However, when I plug in the original equation in WolframAlpha and see the steps, they used two substitutions ($v$ and $u$ as I did), but they got a completely different first order ODE:

$$-2vu^2 + u'(v^2+1)u = 0$$ whose solution is $u=c_1(v^2+1)$

I don't understand what I did wrong. The similarity of the two solutions makes me think I did a typo but I double-checked and can't find the error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you set $y'=v$, I do not see how you could arbitrarily state that $y''=v'v$ or any of the other substitutions you have drawn. Those degrees of freedom shouldn't exist, am I missing something in your derivation?

Comment: I think it is $v = y’$ and $y’’ = v\frac{dv}{dy}$  but not worked it through.

Comment: It is a parameter change from $x$ to $y$, so that, among others, $y'=v(y)$. As a consequence, $y''=v'(y)y'=v'v$ and $y'''=v''(y)v(y)^2+v'(y)^2v(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

What we have for free (the underlying structure of which would never change with any valid substitution) is the following rearrangement of the original ODE

$$\frac{y'''}{y''} = \frac{2y'y''}{1+y'^2}$$

which has the associated ODE

$$k_1 y'' = 1 + y'^2$$

for arbitrary constant $k_1$. This is exactly integrable again to get

$$y' = \tan\left(\frac{x+k_2}{k_1}\right) \implies y = k_1\log\left|\sec\left(\frac{x+k_2}{k_1}\right)\right|+k_3$$

Comment: Could you explain how you came up with $\frac{y'''}{y''} = $k_1y''$? and how did we get from the right side in the first equation to the right side of the second equation? I'm asking  since I never saw such a powerful method for solving ODEs!

Comment: @johndoe those two things are not equal, there was an intermediate step with logs I chose not to include. Directly when you integrate, you get that the log of one side equals the log of the other plus a constant. At that point, why keep the logs?

Answer (score 1):

The original equation is easily separable as
$$
\frac{y'''}{y''}=\frac{2y'y''}{1+y'^2}\implies y''=C(1+y'^2)
$$
which is again separable.

One could get to this also with the parameter change $y''=v(y')$, so that $y'''=v'(y')v(y')$.

Comment: What does $\frac{y'''}{y''}$ signify and how did we integrate that? I'm confused!

Comment: Both sides are logarithmic derivatives $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$. The integration additive constant becomes a factor after exponentiation.